# Simple temperature converter

Tags: c#, winforms, converting

Below is my first attempt at programming a Celsius to Fahrenheit converter in C# winforms. I'm looking for tips and advice on improving my style and what I can do to make the code more efficent/proper, or is it good as is? I apologize ahead of time if i've forgotten any details and would be happy to provide more upon request.

```
namespace TemperatureConverter
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Initalize the handler to allow use of only control/number characters.
        this.txtCelsius.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtCelsius_KeyPress);
        // Limits user's inpute to 5 characters max.
        txtCelsius.MaxLength = 5;
        // Prevents the user from resizing window.
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    }
    // Main function. Converts the input into Fahrenheit and outputs to the targeted label.
    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double C;
        double F;

        C = double.Parse(txtCelsius.Text);
        F = C * 9 / 5 + 32;
        lblFahrenheit.Text = F.ToString();
    }
    // Prevents user from entering anything other than Number and Control characters.
    private void txtCelsius_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this piece of code it does not really matter because it it so short, but if it were longer you should start avoiding one letter variables and given them proper names like `celciusValue`, `fahrenheitValue` and `eventArgs`.

Comment: `e` is a pretty typical name for the `eventArgs` argument.  I think .NET may even default to it under some circumstances.  Doesn't mean it isn't worth changing, but it *is* a convention.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main change is separation of logic and User Interface. Firstly the calculation methods should ideally not reside in UI methods like event handlers.

Secondly the calculations should really be in it's own class, (but this application is just small enough that it is not ENTIRELY necessary).

---

in programming we hate [Magic Numbers](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-using-magic-numbers-and-string-literals-in-your-code/). If you can, move any numbers littered around your code and name them something useful.

so:

As `9/5 + 32` is equal to **1.8 (+32)** and that number represents the scale difference, if we declare that at the top of our code like

```
double FAHRENEHEIT_SCALE_DIFFERENCE = 1.8;  
double FREEZING_POINT_OF_WATER = 32;
```

Depending on how much you have covered thus far you should then move the actual conversion to it's own method.

(because if you come back to this code in 12-18months will you be able to remember what it does? What if it quadruples in size with more features?

So:

I would suggest something along the lines of

```
public double convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius)
{
  return celsius * FAHRENEHEIT_SCALE_DIFFERENCE + FREEZING_POINT_OF_WATER;
}
```

Next, 
you can tidy the button click.

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double celsius = double.Parse(txtCelsius.Text);
    lblFahrenheit.Text = convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(celsius);
}
```

---

Finally the golden change is the separation of the logic from the interface.

Now that you have a simple method that is separate from the actual screen; you could move it, and all similar methods into it's own `TemperatureConverter` class, or something similar.

Comment: Your refactoring is broken - check the conversion in the original code (hint: `a * b + c` is not the same as `a * (b + c)`)

Comment: I think your constants have unfortunate names, though. `FAHRENEHEIT_SCALE_DIFFERENCE` should be `CELSIUS_TO_FAHRENHEIT_FACTOR` (remove the typo in Fahrenheit, include Celsius, and it’s not a difference, but a factor), and `FREEZING_POINT_OF_WATER` – in most of the world, a constant of that name would be either 0 or 273.15. I think I’d use `CELSIUS_TO_FAHRENHEIT_OFFSET`. Just my 2 cents, of course.

Comment: You should use `decimal.TryParse()` instead.  What if the user asks to convert `five` or `50C`?

Comment: SCREAMING_CAPS is not in favor as constant naming convention for C#. They should be PascalCased, e.g. `FahrenheitScaleDifference` and `FreezingPointOfWater`.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I disagree, SCREAMING_CAPS is to my eye's considerably cleaner given the propensity to PascalCase Public properties. Consts are rather a separate concept and should be marked as such.

Comment: @Bobson most definitely but that borders on premature optimization. There are many other changes I would also make regarding input sanitization but I felt they were out of scope.

Comment: @apieceoffruit to each their own, of course, but it's not current convention. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/242549/3312

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer yeah, for this very reason I have taken stylecop off my VS required app list and instead use custom Resharper settings. I also remove the preceding I in front facing interfaces. 

If you haven't I suggest reading bob martin's clean code.

It's not gospel or anything but it makes you think of the point/relevance of standards.

(although I still love my occasional closing brace comment...)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would encapsulate the logic:

```
public interface ITemperature
{
    double Temperature
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface ITemperatureConverter<in T, out U> where T: ITemperature where U: ITemperature
{
    U Convert(T temperature);
}

public abstract class TemperatureBase : ITemperature
{
    private readonly double temperature;

    protected TemperatureBase(double temperature)
    {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public double Temperature
    {
        get
        {
            return this.temperature;
        }
    }
}

public sealed class Fahrenheit : TemperatureBase
{
    public Fahrenheit(double temperature) : base(temperature)
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator Fahrenheit(double temperature)
    {
        return new Fahrenheit(temperature);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Temperature + "F";
    }
}

public sealed class Celsius : TemperatureBase
{
    public Celsius(double temperature) : base(temperature)
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator Celsius(double temperature)
    {
        return new Celsius(temperature);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Temperature + "C";
    }
}

public sealed class FahrenheitToCelsiusConverter : ITemperatureConverter<Fahrenheit, Celsius>
{
    public Celsius Convert(Fahrenheit temperature)
    {
        if (temperature == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("temperature");
        }

        return new Celsius((5f / 9f) * (temperature.Temperature - 32f));
    }
}

public sealed class CelsiusToFahrenheitConverter : ITemperatureConverter<Celsius, Fahrenheit>
{
    public Fahrenheit Convert(Celsius temperature)
    {
        if (temperature == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("temperature");
        }

        return new Fahrenheit(temperature.Temperature * (9f / 5f) + 32f);
    }
}
```

Your UI code then becomes:

```
private readonly CelsiusToFahrenheitConverter celsiusToFahrenheitConverter = new CelsiusToFahrenheitConverter();

private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblFahrenheit.Text = celsiusToFahrenheitConverter.Convert(double.Parse(txtCelsius.Text));
}
```

Comment: This feels like serious overkill for the given problem-statement, but, if you are going to go this far, why not take it the full-monty, throw in a Kelvin converter, and then you only need to have a MyUnit-Kelvin converter, and you can then ue any unit you want. The Model you suggest here could be the basis of that.

Comment: Couldn't agree more! But the problem at hand only needed C -> F. More can be created pretty easily.